# how can random grouping a matrix in r?

Tags: r

I want to generate m^2 element from bi-variate normal, then divided them to m group with m size. 
each row of this matrix is pair and i need to keep it.

for example I generated a matrix.

```
m <- 5
mu <- c(1,2)
Sigma <- matrix(c(5,2,2,10), nr=2)
A <- mvrnorm(n = m^2, mu, Sigma, tol = 1e-6, empirical = FALSE, EISPACK = FALSE)
A

            [,1]        [,2]

 [1,]  2.9553065  5.98908423

 [2,] -1.8670295  5.10591725

 [3,]  0.4525815 -1.38689984

 [4,] -0.2505460  0.55450966

 [5,] -1.1744521  2.45349132

 [6,]  0.2772808  2.51802656

 [7,]  1.2252624  2.68861855

 [8,] -0.3800679 -0.95790121

 [9,] -1.8994312 -2.65912013

 .
 .
 .

 [22,]  0.1072236  0.07729866

 [23,]  2.1108011 -0.64723640

 [24,]  0.2431816  1.04820102

 [25,]  0.7361761  1.96943700
```

How can I do this?

Please help me
Thanks
Nasrin

Comment: Please improve the formatting of your question (http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), and remove the superfluous newlines. Right now, your question is hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to determine which samples are going to end up in each of the `m` random samples:

```
random_indices = matrix(sample(m^2), m, m)
random_indices
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   14    1   16   21   23
[2,]   11   10   24    3   15
[3,]   17    2   13   20   19
[4,]   22    5   18    8    6
[5,]    9   25    7    4   12
```

Next, we need to extract the actual samples. Here, each sub-sample contains the samples from your `A` matrix mentioned in the rows of `random_indices`. The result is a list with for each of the `m` subsets, `m` samples:

```
lapply(seq_len(nrow(random_indices)), function(x) A[random_indices[x,],])
[[1]]
           [,1]      [,2]
[1,]  2.7177656  6.844050
[2,]  2.2583187  2.824858
[3,] -2.3599720 -6.089002
[4,] -0.8386464  3.994062
[5,]  3.4257535  1.107403

[[2]]
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,] -0.5054434 -1.2499055
[2,] -1.6383755  7.6674873
[3,]  3.1938874 -3.1286704
[4,]  0.6332935  3.4084193
[5,] -3.0407672 -0.6030366

[[3]]
           [,1]      [,2]
[1,]  0.2296299 5.0697808
[2,]  0.6292743 0.9794591
[3,]  1.1109314 7.3588483
[4,]  2.1835536 3.0048715
[5,] -0.2173142 1.4850735

[[4]]
            [,1]     [,2]
[1,]  3.36705377 1.487134
[2,] -0.05987684 4.881800
[3,]  0.61090216 3.632019
[4,]  0.39473322 1.067586
[5,]  5.77516329 8.382878

[[5]]
           [,1]      [,2]
[1,] -2.3590412 -2.133053
[2,]  0.2696948  3.986496
[3,]  0.2362004 -6.120856
[4,]  1.9769119  7.343788
[5,]  2.4542632  1.870695
```